# How to calculate total price of multiple items in cart in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a carts table where column is----> "id", "user_id", "product_id", "quantity". See the image [image: carts table image]

here is ther products table [image: products table]

When a user add item into cart ,I want to get total price of products which is added into cart by the user. How to do that?

Here is the cart model [image: cart model]

Here is the product model [image: product model]

Comment: Do you have the relationships defined in your models?

Comment: yes, I defined that into models

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this. I'll post one option as an answer.

Comment: please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

You can edit the existing relationship or create a new relationship for Cart in the User model to join the products table and do a calculation to get the total price.

```
//User model
public function cartsWithProductPrice(){
 return $this->hasMany(Cart::class)
             ->join('products', 'carts.product_id', 'products.id')
             ->select('carts.*', 
                      \DB::raw('carts.quantity * products.price as price')
                     );
}
```

And when you call for example `User::with('cartsWithProductPrice')->find(1);` it should give you the cart relationship with a field named `price` with total price.

Hope that this will point you in the right direction.